# Different textbox values need to be seperated

Tags: c#, textbox

```
Random number = new Random();
int num = number.Next(0, 11);
textBox2.Text += num.ToString();
```

When the random numbers are being added to the textbox they are being connected, I need them to be seperate numbers. I tried fixing it by inserting a blank space after every button click so that it would register as different numbers but its still connecting the 2 numbers.

Later when I add the 2 numbers they register as one, this is the code i use for the addition of the 2 textboxes

```
decimal a, b;
a = Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
b = Decimal.Parse(textBox2.Text);
textBox3.Text = (a + b).ToString();
```

Comment: try ````textBox2.Text += String.Format("{0} ", num);````  I don't understand what you are trying to do in the second block of code.

Comment: It's not very clear: what work have you already done (in extenso, for example you talk about a button click which code is not present) and what are you trying to achieve with all this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "connected"? Do you mean they become one number as in 8 and 9 becoming 89? And can you show us the code where you added a space and it didn't work? Also, you probably want to split the text later when you're attempting to parse it.

Comment: As a side note, you should declare your `Random` variable as a class-level static variable because... [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/767999/8967612).

Comment: Are you expecting `textBox2` to contain one number, or multiple distinct numbers?  The description implies the latter to me, but the calculation at the end implies the former.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnShowNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random number = new Random();
            int num = number.Next(0, 11);
            int c = 0;
            textBox2.Text += ($" {num.ToString()} 0169"); // ads random number and space

            decimal a, b;
            a = Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            b = Decimal.Parse(textBox2.Text); // cant parse if a decimal has " " 
            
            string nr = b.ToString();

            label1.Text = b.ToString() ;
            
            
            
            
            lblContains.Text = nr.Replace("0169", " ");

        }
    }
}
```

Maybe converting decimal to string and then showing string and replacing (in this example) 0169 to space?

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJUr2.png)

Comment: And what will happen when trying to use `Decimal.Parse` on the value `"10 6 8 4"`?

Comment: maybe convert decimal then to string and use Replace() to get spaces?

Answer (score 0):

They are "being connected" because `textBox2` can have only one value, and that value is a string.  Everything you do is either writing to or reading from that one string value.

So if you do this:

```
textBox2.Text = "1";
```

And then this:

```
textBox2.Text += "2";
```

Then `textBox2` doesn't have two values, `1` and `2`.  It has one value, `"12"`.

---

You *could* create your own data serialization standard for this simple case.  For example, you mentioned including a blank space to separate the values.  In that case your immediate goal is for the value to be `"1 2"`.  Each time you append to the text value, de-serialize what's already there and add to that data and then re-serialize it.  For example:

```
// generate your random number
Random number = new Random();
int num = number.Next(0, 11);

// de-serialize the text into an array of numbers
var values = textBox2.Text.Split(' ').ToList();

// add your new value
values.Add(num.ToString());

// re-serialize the data back to the text box
textBox2.Text = string.Join(' ', values);
```

---

Later, when you want to get that value to perform calculations, you would again de-serialize it.  For example:

```
var b = textBox2.Text.Split(' ').Select(x => Decimal.Parse(x));
```

Since `b` is *multiple values* then clearly you can't just add it to a value.  If your intent is to add *all of them* then you can add their sum:

```
textBox3.Text = (a + b.Sum()).ToString();
```